# Need help in sorting the list by category of Automobile company's products in Java or C#

Tags: java, c#, sorting, arraylist, collections

I need help in sorting an ArrayList by category of Automobile Company's product from low cost to high cost.
Sorting order should be Alto, Swift, Brezza (low cost to high cost).
For Example:

**My Input:** Brezza, Alto, Alto, Brezza, Swift, Alto, Swift, Alto

**Expected Output:** Alto, Alto, Alto, Swift,Swift, Brezza, Brezza

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you show the problematic part of your code assuming you already made a few tries and the result is not satisfactory for you?

Comment: Thanks for the response, actually Im looking for a fresh idea or logic. if you have any logic to handle this requirement, could you please share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution works for C#: Use LINQ's `OrderBy` and assign an index to each possible string:

```
List<string> input = new List<string> { "Brezza", "Alto", "Alto", "Brezza", "Swift", "Alto", "Swift", "Alto"};
List<string> result = input.OrderBy(x => x switch  { "Alto" => 1, "Swift" => 2, "Brezza" => 3, _ => 4 }).ToList();
```

If a string is neither of Brezza, Alto or Swift, I assign the highest index, which means that these items will be at the end of the list.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/N7XQZi

Comment: this code work c# language version 8.0 or greater

Answer (score 0):

in C#:

```
List<string> input = new List<string> { "Brezza", "Alto", "Alto", "Brezza", "Swift", "Alto", "Swift", "Alto" };
var sortedList = input.OrderBy(x => Enum.Parse(typeof(Priority), x)).ToList();

public enum Priority
{
  Alto,
  Swift,
  Brezza
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java

```
List<String> input = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Brezza", "Alto",
   "Alto", "Brezza", "Swift", "Alto", "Swift", "Alto"));
Map<String, Integer> order =
        Map.of("Brezza", 3, "Alto", 1, "Swift", 2);

input.sort(Comparator.comparing(name -> order.get(name)));
System.out.println(input);
```

Prints

```
[Alto, Alto, Alto, Alto, Swift, Swift, Brezza, Brezza]
```

The problem is that you need to maintain some external ordering (like the map above) which can be cumbersome if you add new models. Ideally, you would have a `Car` class which would contain a relative cost attribute.  Let's say the attribute is obtained by `getRating` where the rating of the vehicle relates the cost.

Then you could do.

```
List<Car> cars = ...
cars.sort(Comparator.comparing(Car::getRating));
```